# Pyspark not receiving data sent from kafka Producer

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am new to PySpark. I have written a Kafka Producer that produces JSON data and sends that data to the 'test' topic. On the other side, I am trying to receive the Kafka-produced data by consuming the 'test' topic in PySpark's readStream, but it's not printing any values on the PySpark side.

Below is my code:-

Kafka Producer code:-

```
import json
import requests
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from time import sleep

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                         value_serializer=lambda x:json.dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))


for i in range(50):
    res = requests.get('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json')
    res = json.loads(res.content.decode('utf-8'))['iss_position']
    # print('res', res)
    res = str(res).replace("'", '"')
    data = json.loads(str(res))
    print(data)
    producer.send('test', value=data)
    sleep(5)
    producer.flush()
```

Kafka Data to be sent:-

```
{'longitude': '3.1922', 'latitude': '50.6512'}
```

Pyspark Consumer Code:-

```
import sys

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import split
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType



if __name__ == "__main__":

    bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092"
    subscribeType = "subscribe" 
    topics = "test"

    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("StructuredKafkaWordCount")\
        .getOrCreate()

    # spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('OFF')
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")


    
    schema = StructType([ 
        StructField("longitude", StringType(), True),
        StructField("latitude" , StringType(), True),
        ])


    lines = spark\
        .readStream\
        .format("kafka")\
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)\
        .option(subscribeType, topics)\
        .load()


    df = lines.select('*')
  
    # Start running the query that prints the running counts to the console
    query = df\
        .writeStream\
        .outputMode('Append')\
        .format('console')\
        .start()

    query.awaitTermination()
```

Current spark version 3.5.0